# Если ли встроенный способ перебора с добавлением в Set, Map - коллекции?

Tags: java, коллекции, foreach, итераторы, перебор

Для List коллекции на такой случай есть расширенный итератор [ListIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).

А для Set и Map действительно что ли ничего (метод, класс и т. п.) для перебора с добавлением нет?

Comment: А смысл? Они не последовательны, значит совершенно не важно когда ты добавишь элемент

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko на каждое число больше 15, добавить тоже число+7

Comment: И зачем тут итератор? Добавив элемент в множество или мапу ты не знаешь где он появится при итерации, в конце или начале. Итерация отдельно, добавление отдельно

Answer (score 2):

Для `Set` существует итератор:

```
HashSet<String> set= new HashSet<String>();
Iterator iterator = set.iterator(); 
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next());  
}
```

Или так:

```
Set<String> set;
for ( String s : set )
    System.out.println(s);
```

`Map` можно перебрать так(нужно создать свой итератор):

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (entries.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, String> entry = entries.next();
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "  " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Костыльный способ для доступа по индексу(и удалению):

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++) {
    list.add((String) set.toArray()[i]);
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Только обычные итераторы не позволяют добавлять в коллекцию во время её перебора (про это был вопрос). Я знаю как это сделать своими силами. Но хотел убедиться, что в стандартных библиотеках никакого решения (на подобии ListIterator) не предусмотрено.

Comment: @KenyValisamin можно сделать костыльным способом. Добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap и HashSet не гарантируют порядка, поэтому доступ по индексу не имеет смысла. А для перебора и изменения можно использовать стандартный StreamApi

```
Set<Integer> set = Set.of(-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -10);
        set = set.stream()
                .filter(i -> i > 0)    // Отсеиваем отрицательные
                .map(i -> i * 2)       // Умножаем на 2
                .collect(Collectors.toSet()); // Собираем в новый Set
```

Comment: А напишите как будет для этих же чисел: добавить на каждое, которое которое > 1, это же число *2 (то есть на выходе: -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -10, **4, 6, 8, 10** (но так как это Set - без разницы в каком порядке)).

Comment: 1. Что за "of"? (у сета нет такого метода)

Comment: `.map(i -> i > 1 ? i * 2 : i) `

Comment: У класса есть, возвращает новый сэт предопределенный из элементов

Comment: начиная c java 9 действительно есть, хорошо. `.map(i -> i > 1 ? i * 2 : i)` – изменяет. Я может не точно выразился, но нужно именно добавлять, не трогая оригинал: -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -10, _4, 6, 8, 10_ (**ВСЕ эти числа должны содержаться на выходе**). Можно так?

Comment: в сете все элементы уникальны, можно создать список `List <Integer> list = new ArrayList.addAll(set); list.addAll( set.stream().filter...collect(Collectors.toList()));`. Stream не изменяет начальную коллекцию, он порождает поток из исходной, оператор filter фильтрует, map преобразуют каждый элемент (есть и другие) collect - складывает все в новую коллекцию.